# How does SQLite save a newline on MSWindows?

Tags: windows, perl, sqlite, newline

When a text value contains a newline, does SQLite on a Windows machine save the newline as `0x0D0A` or as `0x0A`?

---

Edit: I asked this question because I would like to know if this user defined sqlite function will return the right value if the passed string has a newline in it.

```
#!/use/bin/env perl
use DBI;
# ...
# ....
$dbh->sqlite_create_function( 'bit_length', 1, sub {
        use bytes;
        return length( $_[0] );
    }
);
```

Comment: It saves whatever you hand it. SQLite is not going to inspect the contents and change it unless you tell it to do so.

Comment: If you provide a few lines of code, I (or anyone else) can tell you what happens on a windows box .. right now it's hard to even guess the exact nature of the problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not change strings by itself; as long as you don't explicitly change them with some [function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html), they are treated similar to blobs.

If you have a string like `"Hello, world!\n"` in your code, it will keep that newline style.
If you read the text from a file, it depends on how your language handles newline conversions in text files, but there are not other places where Perl would implicitly convert newlines.